# Trying to compile HelloWorld C with GCC compiler in NDK

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk

So I was getting...
    sys/types.h:124: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'u_int64_t'

So I edited types.h and removed line 124 (I know drastic but I am lost)

```
typedef uint32_t       u_int32_t;
typedef uint16_t       u_int16_t;
typedef uint8_t        u_int8_t;
/* typedef uint64_t       u_int64_t;*/
```

Now I get...

```
Fatal error: invalid -march= option: `armv5te'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: More details on what and how you're compiling will help me understand your question better. As of now, your question doesn't contain enough details to give a meaningful answer